# I can not open existing windows azure project

Tags: windows, azure, cloud

I am trying to open my existing windows azure project on anohter pc. I am using VS2012.
I got this information

Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them. You can still open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
     - Biksad.Admin, "D:\biksad2\Code\Biksad.Admin\Biksad.Admin.ccproj"

Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in this version and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
     - BikSat, "D:\biksad2\Code\BikSat.sln"

Edit: I downloaded and installed azure tools v2.2

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you installed VS2012 version of Azure SDK v2.2.  Try to uninstall SDK then install v2.2 for VS2012 and not for VS2013 from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/

If it still gives the same error message, please provide your exact version of Visual Studio and related parts of the content of the project file.